# SSIS DB2 and Distributed Transactions

Tags: ssis, db2, msdtc, distributed-transactions

I am using Microsoft OLEDB Provider for DB2 to connect to DB2 data base. I have a sequence  container and two execute SQL tasks inside that.
When I set the container transaction option to "Required", I am getting error- "Error Description: Failed to acquire connection. Connection may not be configured correctly or you may not have the right permissions on this connection"
I have set MSDTC properties in server to 
Network DTC Access, Allow remote Clients, Allow InBound and AllowOutbound, and No authentication required, still I am getting the same error.

**Update:**
I have done the same DTC setting on my local machine too where package is running. Still the same error exists.
I created sample package which implements transaction on SQL table and this works fine. Is there any additional setting I need to do for DB2 database?

Answer (score 0):

> I have set MSDTC properties in server to Network DTC Access

you need to enable MSDTC on the computer that is running the package. He is the one who is going to coordinate the SSIS transactions, not the database server

Comment: I enabled MSDTC on computer running package, it did not work.  I created sample package which implements transaction on SQL table and this works fine. Is there any additional setting I need to do for DB2 database?